# Its not redirecting to mobile app after Google login, instead it goes to google.com in react native android

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I used redirectUrl and it's working fine in local development but when i create a Realease apk after it's not working it's redirect to google page.

```
  const result = await Google.logInAsync({
                androidClientId:'31022361841-7431bfbrm8qidpd9l7m9cldn1vd3nl65.apps.googleusercontent.com',

                androidStandaloneAppClientId:'874376514949-m5f77i8pp4dub997jm664pfljle1bu9k.apps.googleusercontent.com',

                 redirectUrl: `${AppAuth.OAuthRedirect}:/oauthredirect` 

                 scopes: ['profile', 'email'],


              });
```

Comment: I think you need to use custom scheme in redirectUrl e.g. myapp://mycallback/login
This should be register with your app so that when google authenticate successfully your app can listen to this custom scheme and launch back the app.

Comment: @MohsinBagwan i am using this code for android app